# Adding surfaces inside a surface in Famo.us

Tags: famo.us

I want another three more surface inside this surface how it possible please help me

This is the surface that I have created.

```
           var firstSurface = new Surface({
                size: [360, 480],

                properties:{
                    backgroundColor:'blue',
                    backgroundImage: "url('img/panel-item-ticks-hq.png')",
                    backgroundSize: '360px 480px',
                    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the famo.us university's layout course. http://famo.us/university/famous-102/layout/1/

Surfaces can't be placed inside each other you can use a container surface which can hold other surfaces you can .add them to the base with the same position but a higher zIndex, you could create a view if one of the current ones doesn't match the pattern your looking for, or you can make an html template and set it as the content of this surface.

Comment: I don't think it's because of the question which seems to be simple, but because of the formatage of the question.
The question is in the title and the post is bad formatted. That's it.

Comment: Alright touche. I edited for the guy so it looks better but it's waiting for peer review.

Comment: and you should add the first bit of your answer as a comment (I've edited it out) to the orignal post..... and people should down vote and give a reason, specially for the noobs